# Is $\{ \emptyset \}$ is a subset of set $\{ \emptyset, 1, 2, 3 \}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is $\{ \emptyset \}$ a subset of set $\{ \emptyset, 1, 2, 3 \}$? 
I know that empty set is subset of every set, but what about $\{ \emptyset \}$? What if 'right set' was just $\{1, 2, 3\}$? Will it still be true that $\{ \emptyset \}$ is a subset of set $\{1, 2, 3\}$?

Comment: The set $A = \{ \emptyset, 1, 2, 3 \}$ has *four* elements. One of them is $\emptyset$.

Comment: Correct : $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set; thus $\emptyset \subseteq A$.

Comment: Now, the question is : is $\{ \emptyset \} \subseteq A$ ? We have to apply the [def of subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#Definitions) ... or lists all the subsetts of $A$.

Comment: $\{\emptyset\}\subseteq A$ if and only if $\emptyset\in A.$ (In general $B\subseteq A$ if and only if every element of $B$ is an element of $A.$)

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{x\}$ is a subset of $\{a,b,c\}$ if and only if $x$ is equal to $a$, $b$ or $c$. So, unless you have a weird definition of $1$, $2$ or $3$, $\{\emptyset\}\nsubseteq\{1,2,3\}$. But $\{\emptyset\}\subseteq\{\emptyset, 1,2,3\}$

*Remark*: The most usual construction of $\Bbb N$ from ZFC defines $0=\emptyset$ and $1=\{\emptyset\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about $\emptyset$, then it is indeed the subset of any set.

If you are asking about $E = \{\emptyset, 1,2,3\}$, then $\emptyset \in E$ and $\emptyset \subset E$.

Moreover, if $S = \{\emptyset\}$ then $S \subset E$.

Comment: It looks to me like the question is asking whether $\{\varnothing\}\subseteq\{\varnothing,1,2,3\}$, which is not what you're answering here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm OP changed the question twice, will redo